# "expo build:..." commands throw same error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

The app builds and runs on both android and iOS and I was able to publish my app to expo. But I get the same error message from all `expo build:...` commands. I want to build an apk, don't really care about the ipa for iOS. The error I get is

```
Request failed with status code 500
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace
```

and here's my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "iiApp",
    "slug": "expo.io/@mcdowellalex/iiApp",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./content/iiLogo.webp",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.inductiveIntelligence.iiApp"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.inductiveIntelligence.iiApp"
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm logged into expo, I was able to publish it

Answer (score 1):

So a strange workaround I found is to open 2 terminals. In the first, run expo start. And once the app is running, run expo build:android in the other terminal. 
I don't think that is what is the expected/intended process, but it worked.